# 'Force' Python to evaluate all boolean expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-expression

Most languages have a way to force 'fail early and often' through forcing all booleans in an if to be evaluate.

Suppose I have the following if statement in Python:

```
if(age>100 or patient_is_brain_dead or patient_lacks_left_arm):
    do something...
```

The problem is I may have forgotten to set either boolean for 'patient_is_brain_dead or 'has_no_left_arm'.

Since most alive people are under 100, tests 2 and 3 happen rarely since Python, seeing the 'or' coming ahead, stops evaluating if age<100 to save time.

My code is heavily compute-bound, so the overhead of testing all three cases will not degrade performance, but would catch a lot of potential bugs that would happen potentially in one-in-500 cases.

Is there a way to force Python to evaluate them all?  Don't suggest reversing the order, because any case could be the rare one(s) depending on user input.

Comment: I think [unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) may be useful here.

Comment: ...or from explicitly checking that `patient_is_brain_dead is not None and patient_lacks_left_arm is not None`, a.k.a. "forgotten to set", and raising an Exception then?

Comment: I think that would work but is a rather roundabout method. I thought putting it in parentheses would do the trick, but alas not.

Comment: The brain-dead and left-arm checks usually *will* happen with the line you wrote, because `or` has to keep going if the left side is false.

Comment: @eSurfsnake, Is that a typo? Given your description, it seems you want the logic `if age < 100 or ... or ...`.

Comment: Yes, typo, now fixed. The point is most people alive are under 100.  Few people are brain dead or lacking an arm.  The problem with Python, with dynamic variable instantiation, is it is easy in complex code with lots of conditions to have 3 conditions, one of which is satisfied 99.99% of the time, yet have a code bug that fails to set other boolleans or vars that occur one-in-ten-thousand times.  It's ugly, but I prefer Jeronimo's answer; converting 'or' to 'not and' forces every test.  Not pretty, but does the trick.

Comment: Converting `or` to `and` doesn't prevent short-circuiting, because `and` short-circuits too. (Also, I'm not sure who Jeronimo is supposed to be.)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you shouldn't *want* to do this in production code. If a couple of variables *should* be Boolean and you need to check if either of them are `True`, you *should* use short-circuiting logic.

So what are your options if, as you say, you want to make sure your code doesn't fail on edge cases? You can use [unit testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) to test all viable scenarios. But this may be overkill for your use case. You can just use an [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert) statement:

```
assert all(isinstance(i, bool) for i in [patient_is_brain_dead, patient_lacks_left_arm])

if age > 100 or patient_is_brain_dead or patient_lacks_left_arm:
    # do something...
```

The benefit of such a solution is it's possible to [turn off](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) `assert` statements via command line `-O` for production code. While, for testing purposes, you can be sure your variables are of the correct type.

Comment: I come from a C systems programming environment.  With compute-intensive code, doing three checks is trivial if what comes next is multiplying two 100 x 100 matrices, or big convolutions with thousands of points.  Better to weed out the user (and programmer) errors, since 99.999% of execution time is not in the redundant checks.

Comment: Yep, so assert will do this for you. I'd say it's also a Pythonic approach.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to explicitly check for `None`. It is not a "roundabout" way, that is just how the language works.

If you want the conditional to fail if any of the variables are not set, you can use `all()` to check that they aren't `None`:

```
if(all(i is not None for i in [age, patient_is_brain_dead, patient_lacks_left_arm]) and
        (age > 100 or patient_is_brain_dead or patient_lacks_left_arm)):
    do something...
```

Comment: that sure is ugly...

Comment: I might say the same about literally any C code ever but we all have our preferences :P

Comment: au, contraire.  C code is usually a lot better looking than this...